# My website is "sharing" the cache, but only on my company network

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

## The Problem

- We have a website running on Google Cloud (CentOS 7) w/ Apache, the site seems to be working well outside our network, but when someone inside the company tries to access/log in it shows another co-worker account logged in, and sometimes we can access some products that we didn't have access before, from here, things get more strange, when we make some request from our site it saves the log and when we check, the user that made the request was the user that you were logged first.
- Whenever we force the refresh(Ctrl + F5 on Google Chrome), the issue seems to "fix" until another user logs in from our network.
- The problem is occurring on others navigators too.
- The system wasn't developed by me and it is a little old, but never had this behavior before.

Bellow, I will be posting some images step by step to clarify what is happening and some lines of code.

## Screenshots

[First, I logged in with this user - Marcelo Correia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3iXr.png)

[When I changed the page, instantly it has changed to my user (This part usually are another user that recently was logged in from our network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsoHS.png)

[Here I made a request from the number that I have to censor: 108. Note that in the top of the page, there is still my user: Nelson Rodrigues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfTRU.png)

[And finally when I check the log, inform that the request was really made by the user I was logged: Marcelo Correia, but somehow is still Nelson Rodrigues on the top and in the field "Nome Usuário"(Username) is set Nelson Rodrigues too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PEJ3.png)

## Our Env

- Host: Google Cloud
- Server: CentOS 7
- Cake PHP 2.6.0
- Javascript/JQuery

## Codes / Some Configs

Our Navbar

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right m-n hidden-xs nav-user user">

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <!--span class="thumb-sm avatar pull-left">
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('user.png');?>
        </spanaaa-->
        <?php echo $this->Session->read('Auth.User.nome')?> <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight">
```

The Cake is getting the user by the session, but when we logged I'm sure we have the name correct -> Marcelo Correia

We are using File based to store the Cache.

```
$engine = 'File';
$duration = '+999 days';
if (Configure::read('debug') > 0) {
$duration = '+10 seconds';
}

/**
 * Configure the cache used for general framework caching. Path information,
 * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this configuration.
 */
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));


/**
 * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache configuration
 * is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings in connections.
 */
Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration
));
```

Our Prefix is not used in any other application.

Session Config:

```
/**
 * Session configuration.
 *
 * Contains an array of settings to use for session configuration. The defaults key is
 * used to define a default preset to use for sessions, any settings declared here will override
 * the settings of the default config.
 *
 * ## Options
 *
 * - `Session.cookie` - The name of the cookie to use. Defaults to 'CAKEPHP'
 * - `Session.timeout` - The number of minutes you want sessions to live for. This timeout is handled by CakePHP
 * - `Session.cookieTimeout` - The number of minutes you want session cookies to live for.
 * - `Session.checkAgent` - Do you want the user agent to be checked when starting sessions? You might want to set the
 *    value to false, when dealing with older versions of IE, Chrome Frame or certain web-browsing devices and AJAX
 * - `Session.defaults` - The default configuration set to use as a basis for your session.
 *    There are four builtins: php, cake, cache, database.
 * - `Session.handler` - Can be used to enable a custom session handler. Expects an array of callables,
 *    that can be used with `session_save_handler`. Using this option will automatically add `session.save_handler`
 *    to the ini array.
 * - `Session.autoRegenerate` - Enabling this setting, turns on automatic renewal of sessions, and
 *    sessionids that change frequently. See CakeSession::$requestCountdown.
 * - `Session.ini` - An associative array of additional ini values to set.
 *
 * The built in defaults are:
 *
 * - 'php' - Uses settings defined in your php.ini.
 * - 'cake' - Saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory.
 * - 'database' - Uses CakePHP's database sessions.
 * - 'cache' - Use the Cache class to save sessions.
 *
 * To define a custom session handler, save it at /app/Model/Datasource/Session/<name>.php.
 * Make sure the class implements `CakeSessionHandlerInterface` and set Session.handler to <name>
 *
 * To use database sessions, run the app/Config/Schema/sessions.php schema using
 * the cake shell command: cake schema create Sessions
 *
 */
    Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake'
    ));
```

## What we already tried

- Change the Session config to PHP, cake, and cache(None of them worked)
- Restart Apache
- Restore an old version of the project
- Change the header from our page

  Make JS do a refresh every time seem a poor solution since we don't know when to do this force refresh.

Sorry if something isn't clear or my grammar isn't correct. Any other information that you may want I will be updating the post as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Looked like a quality question to me. I recently had a similar cache and session problem with codeigniter. At last I realized that I had upgraded the php version to 7.2 and the codeigniter core(specially session library) was too old to work with 7.2. Just wondered if you (or some other guy in the company) upgraded php version or do some work inside php configurations?